# qTip and dynamically added elements issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, qtip

I have page with `UpdatePanel` where I add some forms on click on the page.
In those new added elements I have images that must use `qTip`.

I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
        $('.ttip').qtip({
            content: $(this).attr('tooltip'),
            show: 'click',
            hide: 'click',
            position: {
                my: 'top right',
                at: 'bottom center'
            },
            style: { classes: 'ui-tooltip-light' }
        });
    });
```

And this works with elements that are visibile in the begining.
All elements that use `qTip` have `runat="server"` attribute.
BUT when I add new element with class `ttip` it doesn't work.

Exloring I see that the elements that are visible in the beggining have attribute:

```
data-hasqtip="6"
```

But dynamically added elements doesn't have this attribute.

How can I workaround this?
How to make this somehow live?
**UPDATE BASED ON ANSWER**
I have added this in code behind where I make element visible:

```
// Button click handler that add new element to page
public void AddNewElement(Image image)
{
    image.Visible = true;
    image.ToolTip = "blah";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(),
                        "tmp",
                        @"<script type='text/javascript'>
                            $('.ttip').filter(function(){return !$(this).data('qtip')}).qtip(
                                content: $(this).attr('tooltip'),
                                show: 'click',
                                hide: 'click',
                                position: {
                                    my: 'top right',
                                    at: 'bottom center'
                                },
                                style: { classes: 'ui-tooltip-light' }
                            );
                        </script>", 
                        false);
}
```

But it still doesn't work :(

Comment: You need to `$('.ttip').qtip({..` after elements are dynamically added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have added new elements, reinitialize qTip plugin:

```
$('.ttip').filter(function(){return !$(this).data('qtip')}).qtip(...);
```

Comment: +1, but wouldn't it be better to `.qtip()` outside of the callback? This would apply `.qtip()` to all the elements, regardless of the `data`, right?

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge when I click button to add new element I use `myImage.Visible = true;myImage.ToolTip="some text"` this is in c# codebehind. How to use this example that you provided? DO I need to change my current JS function?

Comment: @Johan you have to reinitialize plugin on new elements. The data() check is to avoid plugin be recalled for already initialized elements which for some plugin (don't know for qTip how this case is handle) can be messy. FYI, some plugin as bootstrap tooltip already get their own delegation method, this seems not to be the case for qTip plugin (just checked DOC, cannot see it)

Comment: @1110 post click handler where you are requesting server for new elements

Comment: I know what your intention is with this code. As you know, `filter()` will iterate _all_ elements and check for the `data`. I thought you `qtip()`:ed each element inside of the callback, but when I look at it now, I noticed that I must have misread it. So never mind, my bad!

Comment: I update my question based on your answer but it seams that I still doing something wrong?

Comment: In browser console I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Comment: @1110 I was talking about the click handler, code you are using to bound click event to button to add new elements, not code you are using to initialize qTip plugin. BTW, yes there is typo in your last posted code, missing `{}` around data object

Comment: I update code a little more... this code is invoked when I click on button. I can't find error around data object?

Comment: @1110 "I can't find error around data object" : `.qtip({...})` not just `.qtip(...)`

Comment: Thanks with big "T" :)